# How to enable Developer Tools always ON in IE

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

How to enable Developer Tools always ON in IE.

Every time I set enable Developer Tools (either by Menu or pressing F12), previous settings like Network capture, profiler On are reset to default.

But that's not the case with Firebug :(

Any registry settings to always enable Developer tools in IE9/IE10?

thanks
HydPhani

Answer (score 1):

You can't configure the network tool or the script profiler to be recording by default. They have to be started manually once F12 is open.

Answer (score 0):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IEDevTools modify the "Disabed" to "Enabled"

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a key located at *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IEDevTools*. After searching around for a loong time I found this key instead does the trick:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IEDevTools

Just set disabled to 0.

Answer (score 0):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/275dd263-8b88-498f-901f-43e9b05a4cb2/f12-developer-tools

12 Developer Tools could be disabled with group policy.

Since you are using Windows 10 home edition, we may consider change the following registry to disable F12 Developer Tools under Internet Exploer 11:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IEDevTools

On the right pane, create a REG_DWORD 32 bit value "Disabled", and set the value to "0x00000001".

Then you would find the F12 developer tools is not listed under the Internet Settings list, and F12 is not function;

To disable F12 Tools under Microsoft Edge, open regedit.exe and navigate to the following path:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\F12 (If no such archive, create one)

On the right pane, add a REG_DWORD 32 bit value called "AllowDeveloperTools", set the value to "0x00000000"

This disables the F12 tools under Microsoft Edge.