# Change Browser Mode to IE8 using Vbscript

Tags: vbscript, configuration, internet-explorer-8, bho, ie8-browser-mode

we have requirement of always opening website in IE8 browser mode (not IE8 document mode) i.e if default browser is IE10 our site should open in IE78 browser mode. I  tried this code;

```
Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=8");
```

in global.asax file but it seems to change browser document mode and not browser mode. Can we change it using vbscript because we have a plugin written in vbscript that changes some of the settings of IE ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relationship:

```
Creator                            Created
server                             document      
users                              browser
```

Servers can control the document mode via scripts, because they host documents.

Users can control the browser mode via the registry, because they install the browser.

**References**

- [How to enable Developer Tools always ON in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294440/1113772)
- [Is there a way to set Quirks Mode by default in IE10 running 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106228/1113772)
- [Can I force IE9 *from the user side* to operate in quirks/standards mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225812/1113772)